# *.csv for reading multiple files not working for me while using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an issue with the *.csv to read multiple csv files while running spark locally. The execution doesn't stop

```
staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")
staticDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("retail_data")
staticSchema = staticDataFrame.schema
```

I tried to test the same script on colab and it worked. I don't know if the issue is due to installation or due to windows.
I also tried to reduce number of files to one file and it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to specify like this

```
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")
```

Try this

```
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/")
```

This will work

Comment: Accept this answer if it solved your problem Owner and editor @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this syntaxe to add different paths at the same time only if you're working with a spark version > 3.0.0

What is the spark version you're using ?

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add `spark.stop()`.

Try this:

```
staticDataFrame = spark.read.format("csv")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("inferSchema", "true")\
.load("./data/retail-data/by-day/*.csv")
staticDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("retail_data")
staticSchema = staticDataFrame.schema
spark.stop()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried this but it didn't work the problem is in the *.csv but when i specify the hole path for a single file for example it works.